# A note on orders in quaternion algebras

Tags: lattices, noncommutative-algebra, lattice-theory, quaternion-algebras

**Definition.** An algebra $B$ over a field $F$ is a **quaternion algebra** if there exists $i,j\in B$ such that $1,i,j,ij$ is a basis for $B$ as a vector space over $F$, where $i^2=a,j^2=b;a,b\in F^\times$.

Throughout, we fix $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

**Definition**. A lattice in a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $V$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule $\mathcal{L} \subset V$ that contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $V$ (as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

I proved that

> Let $V_\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. $\mathcal{L} \subset V$ is a lattice if and only if $\mathcal{L}=x_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus \ldots \oplus x_n \mathbb{Z}$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a basis for $V_\mathbb{Q}$.

**Definition.** An order $\mathcal{O} \subset B$ is a lattice that is also a subring having $1\in B$.

I have two questions:

1. Are any two orders isomorphic as rings?!.
2. What are the orders in the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ (the matrix ring over $\mathbb{Q}$)?!. I found that the following subrings are all orders:
   \begin{align}
   &\begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbb{Z} &n\mathbb{Z} \\
   m\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}
   \end{pmatrix},
   \quad m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^* \\ 
   &\begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbb{Z} & \frac{a}{d}\mathbb{Z} \\
   n\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}
   \end{pmatrix},
   \quad a,d,n\in \mathbb{Z}^* \text{ and } d \mid n, \\
   &\begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbb{Z} & \frac{a}{b}\mathbb{Z} \\
   \frac{c}{d}\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}
   \end{pmatrix},
   \quad a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}^* \text{ and } bd\mid ac.
   \end{align}
   Are there more orders?!. Observe that these three types of orders are all isomorphic as rings.

**Note:** The second question is my main question.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might send an email to John Voight at Dartmouth, who is an expert in these matters and very approachable.

Comment: @PaceNielsen - That was basically the opposite of my first thought, which was this question would be better suited for Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: Reading Voight's book is probably the best way to find the answers to these

Comment: This is the link of the question on Math Stack Exchange. It's unsolvable till now. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699250/a-note-on-orders-in-quaternion-algebras?noredirect=1#comment9944810_4699250

@Kimball

Comment: There is no mention to such a question or such an idea in the book of John Voight. I have the book and I use it frequently in my work. @WatsonLadd

Answer (score 13):

Two orders need not be isomorphic.

First of all, in number fields $K$ other than $\mathbf Q$ not all orders are isomorphic rings (even if they are isomorphic abelian groups): the full ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ is integrally closed, but no other order in $K$ is integrally closed.

In the quaternion algebra $\mathbf H(\mathbf Q)$ we have the two orders
$$
L = \mathbf Z + \mathbf Zi + \mathbf Zj + \mathbf Zk
$$
(called the [Lipschtz quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion))
and the larger order
$$
H = \mathbf Z + \mathbf Zi + \mathbf Zj + \mathbf Z\frac{1+i+j+k}{2}
$$
(called the [Hurwitz quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion)). In $H$ there is a left (and right) division algorithm, so all left (and right) ideals in $H$ are principal. But in $L$ there are nonprincipal left ideals and nonprincipal right ideals (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964945/ideal-class-group-of-lipschitz-fully-integer-quaternions)).  So $H$ and $L$ are not isomorphic rings.

Comment: This is great. 
Can we determine all orders in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$?. In fact, this is my main problem.

Comment: In ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q)$ each maximal order is conjugate to ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Z)$ (Corollary 10.5.5 in Voight's book), so you can focus on orders in ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Z)$. I don't know if they are all classified. Orders in quadratic fields $K$ are known: for each $n \geq 1$ there is a unique order with index $n$ in $\mathcal O_K$ and it is $\mathbf Z+n\mathcal O_K$. In $\mathbf Q^2$ (the "split case"), the integral closure of $\mathbf Z$ is $\mathbf Z^2$, with a unique order of each index $n$: $\mathbf Z(1,1) + n\mathbf Z^2$.

Comment: In your comment, you mentioned that there exist non-isomorphic (as rings) orders in $\mathbb{H}(\mathbb{Q})$. But what about the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. May it possible to show that all orders are isomorphic (as rings)? Or can we find two non-isomorphic orders (as rings) ?!.

Comment: "not every order $\subset \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is contained in a maximal order $\subset \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$" - what do you mean with that? $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ itself is a maximal order.

Comment: To your last question - the subset $\begin{pmatrix}\Bbb Z&3\Bbb Z\\3\Bbb Z&\Bbb Z\end{pmatrix}$ is an order which is not isomorphic to the order $M_2(\Bbb Z)$, as it doesn't contain a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2=-I$ (while the latter does). You can see this easily by reducing modulo $3$.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't focus only on the orders of $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ because not every order $\subset \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is contained in a maximal order $\subset \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. We can focus only on the orders in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ if it's guaranteed that every order is contained in a maximal order. @KConrad

Comment: I was mistaken. See my last comment @Wojowu

Comment: @HusseinEid It is true in this case. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4663754/127263).

Comment: Well, it's true that every order in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is contained in a maximal order. By Corollary 10.5.5 in Voight's book, every maximal order in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is conjugate in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ (hence isomorphic) to $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. So, we can focus on orders of $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ that are contained in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Indeed, 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & m\mathbb{Z} \\ 
n\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}
\end{pmatrix}
$, with $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^*$ defines an order. 
My question is: **Are there more orders ?!.**
@Wojowu

Answer (score 6):

The classification of orders is the topic of chapters 22-24 in my book.  Yes, there are plenty more orders than the ones you listed.

One cheeky answer is that isomorphism classes of orders in $\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are in bijection (inverse to the Clifford map) with similarity classes of nondegenerate, isotropic, ternary quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Z}$.  Examples are $xy-Nz^2$ for every nonzero $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, but I bet you can easily dream up many more.  So the classification you seek is as hard as classifying ternary quadratic forms.  (But at least there is no multiplication law to check!)

Not sure what your goal is, but I'll try my best to give a quick outline.  The first step in the classification is to use the local-global dictionary for lattices, which reduces the question to classifying local orders up to isomorphism; the failure of the relevant local-global principle (reconstructing a global order from its local orders) is handled by strong approximation.

Local orders are first classified by their Eichler invariant.  For the orders you wrote, at a prime $p \mid mn$, the local order at $p$ is residually split = Eichler; these admit a nice classification, as do the residually inert orders.  The residually ramified orders are more complicated; but at least we can classify the Bass orders quite explicitly, and in general an order either has a nontrivial Gorenstein saturation, or it is Gorenstein and then it has a unique minimal superorder obtained from the radical idealizer chain, giving a recursive way to classify them.